# Erasing the first key-value pair from a map (in a for loop) gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, segmentation-fault

I have a `std::map<int, std::string>` and my aim is to remove a key-value pair based on a certain condition. For simplicity, let say, it looks like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::map<int, std::string> m1;

    m1[-2] = "minus two";
    m1[-1] = "minus one";
    m1[0] = "zero";
    m1[3] = "three";
    m1[4] = "four";

    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto &&[key, val] : m1) {
        std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
        if (key == -2 || key == 3) 
            m1.erase(key);
    }

    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Everything looks fine. However, it gives `seg fault` upon running:

```
5
-2: minus two
0: 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I noticed that this only occurs when I try to erase the very first key-value pair e.g. in the above case: `-2: "minus two"`. If I try to erase any other key-value pair (e.g. second key-value pair: `-1: "minus one"`) then I don't get `seg fault`, e.g.

```cpp
    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto &&[key, val] : m1) {
        std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
        if (key == -1 || key == 3) 
            m1.erase(key);
    }

    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;
```

I also noticed that if I erase the first key-value pair outside of the `for` loop then I don't get `seg fault` e.g.

```cpp
    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;
    m1.erase(-2);

    for (auto &&[key, val] : m1) {
        std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
        if (key == -2 || key == 3) 
            m1.erase(key);
    }

    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;
```

One more thing that I noticed is that if there are only two key-value pairs then I don't get `seg fault`:

```cpp
    m1[-2] = "minus two";
    m1[4] = "four";

    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto &&[key, val] : m1) {
        std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
        if (key == -2 || key == 3) 
            m1.erase(key);
    }

    std::cout << m1.size() << std::endl;
```

So, is this an expected behavior? If yes then why? Also, in that case, how can I remove/erase the first key-value pair in the `for` loop itself? or I have to remove/erase them outside of the `for` loop?

Comment: In many languages it is not safe to delete from a container you are iterating over, this includes `std::map` inside a for each loop.

Comment: @Quimby Thanks but why? We have unique keys and we are deleting by `key` not by index then why it's not safe? I should have asked this in the main question but as the question is closed would greatly appreciate it if you can share some more details or some useful links. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Quimby In the case of `std::map`, first I thought it has something to do with removing the root node from the tree and the first key-value being a root node but somewhere I read that it's a balanced binary tree. So, I guess the first key-value pair doesn't have to be the root node, right?

Comment: Ups,sorry I missed the comment. Yes, it has to be the root, but that is not the issue. The issue is iterating over any container requires keeping a state - e.g. current index in the array which will be iteratively incremented or a pointer to tree node in `std::map`. Then, when you delete an element, the state can become invalid - e.g. current node seizes to exist and so cannot be used to get the next one. Worse, the state usually won't know it is invalid, hence the segfault. In theory it can be made to work but it is much easier to write "it is unsafe to modify containers while iterating".

Comment: The implementation would have to keep track of who is currently iterating the container, that can be very expensive and really anti-C++. Just to clarify, it is not unsafe to delete the element, it is unsafe to keep iterating the container after deleting the element. See the duplicate question for the proper way how to restore the state.